# Unable to load dynamic library '/base/php_runtime/modules/curl.so'

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl, google-app-engine-php

I'm using Google Cloud Platform's App Engine with PHP 5.5, and today I started receiving the following error in the logs:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/base/php_runtime/modules/curl.so' - /base/php_runtime/modules/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

It appears just after the following:

```
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

and it happens on different files (root directory, different JS files, etc.). I don't use cURL at all in the calls that are made. They are actually sometimes just simple JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same warning and I've received this answer from google cloud support:

> ph...@google.com    #4 May 18, 2017 12:38AM
>
> These log messages are due to a change we made in the PHP runtime
>   environment for App Engine.  We've rolled that change back, so the
>   messages should no longer appear.

I'm seeing no more warning messages since yesterday so seems solved.

Answer (score 1):

Google have been performing some kind of runtime upgrade which led to this issue.

Their known issues page says it has been happening since "10 May 2017, 12:00AM PDT".

It isn't on https://status.cloud.google.com/ yet, but it is in the Support portal.

Comment: Are you referring to this issue?
 https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/appengine/17003 because that one seems to be resolved already. And mine started happening later, and is still occurring. Where did you find that it would be throwing the same "unable to load dynamic library" error as mine?

Comment: @RoelVermeulen no that's not the one, they still haven't posted one on the Status dashboard about it and when we asked why, they said because it didn't affect many people (go figure). But yes, as the answer below states, they've told everyone their change has now been fully reverted (as of about 6pm UTC last night) but have not yet released any further information.